# Exit Sub after GoSub - Exits the Sub or returns from Gosub

Tags: vb6

I'm working on converting some VB6 code to VB.Net, but at the moment can't actually run the VB6 code to see what it does.

I have in it (the VB6, that is) a construct like this:-

```
Sub MySub

    ' Do works
    If somecondition Then GoSub 10000
    ' More works
    Return

10000
    ' More works still
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

The question is, does that `Exit Sub` return from the `GoSub`, or exit from `MySub`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is wrong as written in the example and will fail on "Return without Gosub."

Consider:

```
Option Explicit

Private Count As Integer

Private Sub TestIt()
    GoSub Something
    MsgBox "Here"
    Exit Sub

Something:
    If Count > 0 Then Exit Sub
    Count = Count + 1
    Return
End Sub

Private Sub Main()
    TestIt
    TestIt
    MsgBox Count
End Sub
```

This will pop up a "Here" and then a "1" message box.

`Exit Sub` exits the subroutine, it is not a synonym for `Return` at all.